# Perform the accuracy assessment after performing classification on an image collection in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification, accuracy-assessment

I have classify an image collection using Random Forest classification method by creating a function and mapping that function over image collection. Now, I am stuck with accuracy assesment. Because accuracy assesment needs to validate the classifier but it is giving error that 'classifier is not defined'. It is because classifier is in a function.

Classification using a Function:

```
function classification(image7){
  var label = 'Class';
  var bands = ['B2', 'B3',  'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI-10m', 'NDBI-20m', 'NDWI-20m'];

  var training = image7.select(bands).sampleRegions({
    collection: trainingsample,
    properties: [label],
    scale: 10
  });
  
  var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train(training, label, bands);
  var classified = image7.select(bands).classify(classifier);
  return classified;
}

var Batch_Classification = Batch_CMRI20m.map(classification);
```

Accuracy Assessment:

```
var validation = Batch_Classification.first().sampleRegions({
    collection: validationsample,
    properties: ['Class'],
    scale: 10
  });
  
validation = validation.classify(classifier);
var ValidationAccuracy = validation.errorMatrix('Class', 'Classification');
print(ValidationAccuracy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the classifier as a property to the classified image and later access it for validation. You have to `sampleRegions()` from the first() image of your image collection; not the classified image. And the validation accuracy can be extracted by creating a confusionMatrix at first.

```
   function classification(image){
      var label = 'Class';
      var bands = ['B2', 'B3',  'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI-10m', 'NDBI-20m', 'NDWI-20m'];
    
      var training = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
        collection: trainingsample,
        properties: [label],
        scale: 10
      });
      
      var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train(training, label, bands);
      var classified = image.select(bands).classify(classifier);
      return classified.set('classifier',classifier);
    }
    
    var Batch_Classification = Batch_CMRI20m.map(classification);

    // Define the validation image and classify it
    var validation = Batch_CMRI20m.first().sampleRegions({
            collection: validationsample,
            properties: ['Class'],
            scale: 10
          }).classify(Batch_Classification.first().get('classifier'));
        
        
     var ValidationAccuracy  = ee.ConfusionMatrix(validation
            .errorMatrix({
              actual: 'Class', 
              predicted: 'classification'
            })).accuracy();

      print(ValidationAccuracy);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It helped me a lot in debugging. But in the end it is still giving an error.


Number (Error)
FeatureCollection.classify: Parameter 'classifier' is required.


Because the "classifier" is in a function. It is a local variable and not global.

Comment: Okay. I have understood. I am still making a mistake by not following this: 'You can add the classifier as a property to the classified image and later access it for validation'. Now, I have rewritten the last statemnent of function as: "return classified.set({classifier: classifier});". And for this "print(ValidationAccuracy)", in the Console the answer came out to be "0.9811320754716981". So am I doing the right thing here?

Comment: Yes, if you completely follow my code you are doing fine.

Comment: @SyedAhmedRaza if your problem is solved, kindly accept the answer.